# (Wired or wireless:) Synchronise two RaspberryPi units over 300m to within 1/48000 s

Tags: communication

I need to synchronise two RaspberryPi units over 300m to within 1/48000 s.

I would like to investigate both wired and wireless solutions.

Suppose I run 2 wire between them: 
 - pinX_on_unitA <--> pinY_on_unitB
 - GroundA <--> GroundB

Now if one unit sets this pin high, the other one should be able to catch the signal.  Is it likely that I will run into difficulties due to the length of the cable?

And is there any wireless solution? Conventional BLE is a potential synchronisation hazard.

Comment: The Pi is pretty irrelevant, it could be asked of any computer.

Comment: There may be a wireless 'hat' unit that does the job for Rπ, so I think it's relevant.

Comment: Whatever you want to do within those constraints would likely be better done with a microcontroller.  You should explain in better detail what the context is.

Comment: Distance won't be a problem; propagation speed will be something like 2.8x10^11 m/sec.  There *will* be signal attenuation over distances; how much depends upon how the two Pis are connected.  For "local" distances, I suspect the limiting factor will be response time of the program reading the signal, and not signal propagation at all.  See the comment from @goldilocks.

Comment: Oops; I confused myself in calculation.  Propagation speed will be about 2.8*10^8 m/s.  Sorry.